# How to convert the object value to double?

Tags: asp.net-mvc

```html
@foreach (DataRow row in Model.Tables[0].Rows){
<tr>
  <td style="text-align:right;">@row["Rate"]</td>
</tr>
}
```

How to change this value @row["Rate"] to double.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use `.ToString("F")`, or `.ToString("N2")`, or `.ToString("G")` as mentioned in the docs [here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.double.tostring?view=netframework-4.8).

Sample;

`@row["Rate"].ToString("N2")`

EDIT: If the data isn't double, you could cast it to double then use .ToString();

`@(((Double)row["Rate"]).ToString("N2"))` or `@((Double)row["rate" ].ToString(" N2"))`

Comment: not working ... Error No overload for method 'ToString' takes 0 arguments

Comment: ->display 0.ToString("N2")

Comment: @JHOng `@(((Double)row["Rate"]).ToString("N2"))` or `@((Double)row["rate" ].ToString(" N2"))`